# ardrone navdata callBack error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my program after subscribing navdata using callBack function, the values returning as zero. The values inside the callBack is giving the actual rot.Z data, but after exiting the function the value 'roll' returned as 0.

```
//Initiate the ROS

ros::init(argc, argv, "waypoint_nav");
ros::NodeHandle n;

velocity_publisher = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/cmd_vel", 10);

pose_subscriber = n.subscribe("/ardrone/navdata", 10, poseCallback);

cout<<endl<<"Roll :"<<roll<<endl;

    ros::spinOnce();
```

}

void poseCallback(const ardrone_autonomy::Navdata::ConstPtr & pose_message )

{

```
roll= pose_message->rotX;

cout<<"navdata x"<<roll<<endl;
```

}

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222202/ardrone-navdata-callback-error/) by [Sriherams](https://answers.ros.org/users/25281/sriherams/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The callback function for subscriber nodes are called on `ros::spinOnce()` execution.
Modify your code like this:

```
//Initiate the ROS

ros::init(argc, argv, "waypoint_nav");
ros::NodeHandle n;

velocity_publisher = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/cmd_vel", 10);

pose_subscriber = n.subscribe("/ardrone/navdata", 10, poseCallback);

while(ros::ok())
{
    ros::spinOnce();
    cout<<endl<<"Roll :"<<roll<<endl;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Ameer Hamza Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/24969/ameer-hamza-khan/) with karma: 96 on 2015-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0